# what is contrast?And it effect on each Pixel value?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new at image processing and am working with pixel values. 
I just learned image pixel brightness now I want to learn contrast.

I searched the Internet  but my brain is not getting it.

I'd like to know if you know some thing that could help?
What is concept of contrast?
What is it's effect on each pixel of image?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your work-in-progress implementation.  Do you have a programming question?

Comment: yes i want to change brightness and contrast of image without using any

Comment: yes i want to change brightness and contrast of image without using any library function i did this code for brightness.

Comment: Brightness concept was so simple i just increase RGB value at each pixel.
But i am getting the concept of contrast.

Comment: i have code but i can not edit in editer i am new at stack overflow